# how to push a view from a ToolBar, BarButtonItem

Tags: iphone, ios4, user-interface

I have a toolbar with 4 UIBarButtonItem's, on click of one of the buttons, i would like to change the current view controller to another view controller.

Could please tell me how i could achieve this??

Thanks,

BR,
Suppi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you use UINavigationBar along with UIBarButtonItem?
If so, then just casual

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:theViewCntrlrYouWant animated:NO];
```

should fit to your wish.

(Edited according to Suppi's observation)
If there's no navigation bar, then smth like:

```
YourViewController * first = [[YourViewController alloc] init];
[self presentModalViewController:first animated:NO];
[first release];
```

Comment: i don't have a UINavigationBar, i use a UIToolBar along with UIBarButtonItem. I used the above code, i get [MapScreen presentViewController:animated:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Comment: Hi, i got it working, you need to use,self presentModalViewController:first animated:NO]; instead.